# How to concatenate JSX elements into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Frustrating times in React world... I need to be able to create markup based on certain criterias. For example, I receive an array of items. I need to check these items, and based on criteria, I need to generate different markup. So for example, I have a function that receives an array of items:

```
processItems(itemArray) {
    // Create an empty array that will hold the final JSX output.
    let buffer = []

    // Somehow push the first required markup into the buffer.
    buffer.push(<div className"container flex center">);

    // ... here we do a switch statement that evaluates each item in the 'itemArray' argument and based on that I create different <div className="XYZ">{...put stuff here...}</div> markup, which I will push into the buffer - which will contain the final JSX output...

    // Now I close the initial container element
    buffer.push(</div>);

    // And return the buffer for display inside the render() function
    return buffer;
}
```

The problem is, I cannot simply do `array.push()` to add individual markups into an array because react doesn't like it for some reason, and I will just end up with gibberish stuff that gets display.

Any ideas how could I possibly do this?

Comment: *"I cannot simply do 'array.push()' to add individual markups into an array because react doesn't like it for some reason,"* It's the same reason you cannot create half of a *DOM element*. JSX is not concatenating *strings* to build *HTML*, it's creating components which ultimately render to DOM elements. If you look at what JSX is converted to it will hopefully make more sense. Paste: `<div><span>foo</span></div>` in here: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=&playground=false .

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I am trying to do a similar thing.  Inside a parser, building JSX depending on the content of a JSON object.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Your solution should look like this:

```
processItems(itemArray) {
    // Create an empty array that will hold the final JSX output.
    let buffer = []

    buffer.push(<div>A</div>);
    buffer.push(<div>B</div>);
    buffer.push(<div>C</div>);


    // And return the buffer for display inside the render() function
    return (
        <div className"container flex center">
            {buffer}
        </div>
    );
}
```

JSX is not HTML and you cannot assemble the html elements in multiple steps.

Comment: Yes, my solution does look like that at the end, in the sense that in the render() function I do display {buffer} between a div. But I think my problem is what you pointed out, that I was somehow hoping/wanted to assemble the final output/html by pushing the contents into an array first. Which apparently not possible. Sigh...

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is that in render() I can use any number of HTML elements to display, as long as they sit between an outermost div. On this notion, why can't I just simply put all those HTML elements into a variable or an array, and display that inside the outermost div? That's basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @pentool you can.

Comment: Would you be so kind and post a quick example? I've been trying to do this in the past 5 hours and regardless how I slice it, it just simply doesn't work.

Comment: @pentool just return an array, then use it in the outer div exactly the same as in my answer: `{array_you_returned}`

Comment: That doesn't work.

`let output = []; output.push(<div classname="swiper-slide">); output.push(<div className="quiz-title flex-item-first">{pageItems.sQuestion}</div>); output.push(</div>);`

When I do
```<div>{output}</div>```
my output contains `"); output.push"`

Comment: You **CANNOT** assemble html elements by parts. In my answer I have already provided how you rewrite this very code. What is the problem with implementing it in a way I demonstrated?

Comment: But in your example you pointed out to output `<div>{buffer}</div>`. That is what I'm doing. But I have to put something into `buffer` first. So basically it means that I can only put a single line of HTML into `buffer`?

Comment: 1. Not html but react elements 2. `buffer` is an array. I updated the answer to demonstrate it's an array.

Comment: Ah, I see! So basically you have to push items into the array with *both* the opening and a closing div.