# JSX concat elements webpack + babel compilation error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to concat JSX elements and I get a compilation error

I get the following error: 'Syntax error: Unexpected token'

The problem is that the compiler sees an unclosed tag `ul` (second line: `html.push(ul)`) and think that the rest of the code should be an JSX element.

Function I get the error:

```
walkOnFilter (crumb, html) {
    var keys = Object.keys(crumb)
    html.push(<ul>)

    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      let node = crumb[key]
      html.push(<li>{key}</li>)
      if (!_.isEmpty(node)) {
        this.walkOnFilter(node, html)
      }
    })

    html.push(</ul>)
  }
```

I create the app with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

**EDIT**

This is how I create the html:

```
buildFilters () {

    let html = []
    for (let filter of this.props.filters) {
        this.walkOnFilter(filter, html)
    }

    return (
      <ul>{html}</ul>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to directly push a DOM element to the real DOM tree instead of React virtual DOM? If you are, I strongly suggest you NOT do that since it's against the design principle of react. Please refer to this article if you want to loop through an array and render multiple components. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @LiutongChen I think, no. I just update my question to see how I push the html. I try to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476075/how-to-concatenate-jsx-elements-into-an-array

Comment: @LiutongChen Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do ? Recursively build an ul list with children and grandchildren ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how JSX works. You need to create nested elements, like

```
walkOnFilter (crumb) {
  return (
    <ul>{
      Object.keys(crumb).reduce((items, key) => {
        const node = crumb[key]

        items.push(<li>{key}</li>);
        if (!_.isEmpty(node)) {
          items.push(<li>{walkOnFilter(node)}</li>);
        }
        return items;
      }, [])
    }</ul>
  );
}

buildFilters () {
  return (
    <ul>{
      Array.from(this.props.filters, filter => 
        <li>{this.walkOnFilter(filter)}</li>
      )
    }</ul>
  )
}
```

so each call creates a new `ul` component with the children that you want it to have.