# Add JSX to Array object Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In one of my component, I want to modify a fontsize and add a JSX to one of the property in array of objects.
Is there someway to do it?

Example:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Page A',name1: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page B',name1: 'Page A', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page C',name1: 'Page A', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page D',name1: 'Page A',  uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page E',name1: 'Page A',  uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181,
  }]

let graphData = []; 
let count = 0; 
data.map((d) => {
    graphData.push({"name": d.name + '' + d.name2, "profit": d.amt,"reve": d.p,v});
  }
```

I want to push first value as JSX , something like this 
   `"name":(<div>d.name + '' + d.name2</div>)`

Is there someway to do this?

Comment: You can push html or JSX as a string, but you have to parse it as JSX where you want to render it. Where do you want to modify the fontsize?

Comment: I want to modify the Yaxis labels being displayed in recharts BarChart. Basically, I am modifying dataKey of Yaxis. As they are not being displayed correctly.                 
              <YAxis
              width={this.getWidth(data)}
              // dy={-12}
              tickMargin={10}
              interval={0}
              dataKey="name"
              type="category"
              tickLine={false}
            />

Comment: Are you trying this in React? . If so have a look at template literals

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/yvo1kpn9vj

Comment: Yes you can.  [JSX gets compiled to objects](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects) so you'll have an array of objects representing React elements.

Comment: Check if this solves your problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/9111km720r?fontsize=14

Comment: Template literals didn't solve my issue. Since, I am using recharts library BarChart Component,JSX are not getting render in any of it's props because rechart has been written using SVG elements. I came to know this from one of the issues posted on github.  https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/347

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as String. You can use + concatenate or Template Strings

```
data.map((d) => {
    graphData.push({"name": `<div>${d.name}${d.name2}</div>`});
  }
```

Comment: You missed `` here

Answer (score 0):

do the following :

```
data.map((d) => {
    graphData.push(`<div> name : ${d.name} ${d.name1} </div>`)
  }
```

[i think this issue is the same as yours try looking at it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40476075/10320298)